# Change facebook play now button link

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have an app on facebook.

I want to change the link on the play now button to be different.

is it possible though any API or configuration ??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible to alter Facebook's UI in that manner.

You have no control on how your application/game displayed in that view nor ability to change buttons.

Actually "Play Now" only appears for Games for non games Applications it'll be "Use Now", beware that wording may (and probably will at some point) change without any notice.

Comment: one more question in addition to that : Can we change the link for that button ? I think the answer is NO.

Comment: That link is the very same link as one that appears under every feed story by your App/Game. You cannot change where it points to, but you have some control over it and with some work (it not that hard) you can get it serve your needs. Look into my answer to following question : [Facebook apps redirecting "via {APP_NAME}" to an existing pages](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10467644/facebook-apps-redirecting-via-app-name-to-an-existing-pages).